# How to insert array into MySQL when varchar must be inserted

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, varchar

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZcS.png)  I have a form that collects info of: year(**int**), Case number(**varchar**) and Time received(**varchar**). Since year is a number, I set **int** in MySQL, then Case number and Time Received has both numbers and letters therefore I had set **varchar** in MYSQL. I used array because I insert a lot of records. Im using **mysql_real_escape_string()** for the array. But it did not work. How can I pass the array which has letters, symbols, and numbers to insert into MySQL? Thank you.

```
//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && isset($_REQUEST['year']) ) {
  foreach ($_REQUEST['year'] as $k=> $value ){ // loop through array

    $year     = $_REQUEST['year'];
    $c_no        = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['cs']);
    $t_r        = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['t_r']);


$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year, case_no, t_received) VALUES 
   ($year[$k], $c_no[$k], $t_r[$k])");
}
}
?>
```

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add more fields using jQuery</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="year[]" value="" placeholder="Year"/><input type="text" name="cs[]" value="" placeholder="Case no"/><input type="text" name="t_r[]" value="" placeholder="Time Received"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
$(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
    }
});
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
input[type="text"]{height:20px; vertical-align:top;}
.field_wrapper div{ margin-bottom:10px;}
.add_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
.remove_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-    bottom;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="codexworld_frm" action="" method="post">
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img     src="add-icon.png"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be better if you set year VARCHAR(4) , Case number VARCHAR(255)  and Time received DATETIME/TIMESTAMP.
just my two cents

Comment: Thanks Willy Pt Yeah. Well, Thank you for reminding. I heard a datatype dictionary for proper way of initializing size, and type of datatypes. I also need that datetime/timestamp. Could it be alright to just add new column in MySQL and put the DATETIME/TIMESTAMP there?

Comment: @WillyPt advice is right. You can use `TIMESTAMP` datatype and set it's default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so you won't need to always include it to your query, it will be automatically included there.

Comment: Is changing the html/javascript to get a slightly diffrent format of the POST data an option?

Comment: It is highly recommended that you use PDO instead of mysqli.

Comment: @ryantxr : PDO is my weapon of choice as well, but why is it _highly_ recommended?

Comment: PDO helps produce cleaner code. `mysql_real_escape_string` would not be necessary with PDO. It uses exceptions which can be caught. Prepared statements.

Comment: @ryantxr  "mysql_real_escape_string" - I think you're confusing mysql and mysqli ;-) [mysqli](http://docs.php.net/mysqli) supports [prepared+parametrized statements](http://docs.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements) and [exceptions](http://docs.php.net/class.mysqli-sql-exception) as well.

Comment: @rmondesilva, yeah but I am doing is. Im inserting data into MySQL which is already recorded. This records were already recorded in the book so Im only just transfer it into the system.

Comment: @ryantxr I also use PDO. I should be doing what you are recommending.

Comment: @JerumLabsan Okay I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is submitted _POST (or _REQUEST) will look like this

```
array (
  'year' => 
  array (
    0 => '2001',
    1 => '2010',
  ),
  'cs' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
  ),
  't_r' => 
  array (
    0 => '12:00:00',
    1 => '13:00:00',
  ),
  'submit' => 'SUBMIT',
)
```

It would be nicer if it looked like

```
array(
    'records' = array(
        0=>array('year'=>'2001', 'cs'=>'1', 't_r'=>'12:00:00'),
        0=>array('year'=>'2010', 'cs'=>'2', 't_r'=>'13:00:00'),
    ),
)
```

That would require changing the javascript code (and I'm too lazy for that right now...so I'm using the [SPL MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) to "simulate" that data format)

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    // add tests for is_array() POST[year], POST[cs] and POST[t_r]

    // this will make mysqli throw an exception whenever an operation results in an 
    // (mysql) error code other than 0 -> no further error handling included in this script....
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');

    // create a prepared statement and bind the parameters, see http://docs.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year, case_no, t_received) VALUES (?,?,?)');
    if ( !$stmt->bind_param('sss', $year, $caseno, $time) ) { // binding all parameters as strings ...let mysql's type system handle it...
        yourErrorHandlerHere(); // or throw an exception....
    }
    // when ever the statement is executed, the current values (at _that_ moment) in $year, $caseno and $time will be used where the ? are in the statement

    // this wouldn't be necessary if the POST body looked like record[1][year]=2001&....
    $mit = new MultipleIterator;
    $mit->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator($_POST['year']) );
    $mit->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator($_POST['cs']) );
    $mit->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator($_POST['t_r']) );

    foreach( $mit as $record ) {
        echo 'executing statement with [', join(',', $record), "]<br/>\r\n";
        // assign the values to the bound parameters
        list($year,$caseno,$time) = $record;
        // and then execute the statement (with those values)

        /*
        you might want to wrap this in a try-catch block, so a single faulty record will not throw off your entire script.
        You might also want to look into transactions (in case a single faulty record is supposed to roll back the entire operation)
        see http://docs.php.net/language.exceptions , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html
        */
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

edit: 
a) To allow NULL values you should replace empty strings by NULL in the parameters

```
...
// replace empty strings by NULL
$record = array_map(
    function($e) {
        return 0<strlen(trim($e)) ? $e : NULL;
    },
    $record
);

// assign the values to the bound parameters
list($year,$caseno,$time) = $record;
...
```

b) I don't know why and where you would need the iterator's key in this scenario, but ....

```
<?php
$data=array(
    'maj'=>new ArrayIterator(array('A','B','C')),
    'min'=>new ArrayIterator(array('a','b','c')),
    'foo'=>new ArrayIterator(array('do'=>'re', 'mi'=>'fa', 'so'=>'la', 'ti')),
);

$mit = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$mit->attachIterator( $data['maj'], 'majuscule' );
$mit->attachIterator( $data['min'], 'minuscule' );
$mit->attachIterator( $data['foo'], 'lalala' );

foreach( $mit as $r ) {
    var_export($r);
}
```

prints

```
array (
  'majuscule' => 'A',
  'minuscule' => 'a',
  'lalala' => 're',
)array (
  'majuscule' => 'B',
  'minuscule' => 'b',
  'lalala' => 'fa',
)array (
  'majuscule' => 'C',
  'minuscule' => 'c',
  'lalala' => 'la',
)array (
  'majuscule' => NULL,
  'minuscule' => NULL,
  'lalala' => 'ti',
)
```

Comment: This is just my first time to build an array type form. So I'm really confused about it. Regarding more to the **MultipleIterator**. I applied it in coding. This helps a lot. I read about it it says ""Warning: Illegal type returned from MultipleIterator::key()" and the result of (int)0 as the key for all iterations. " so mean I tried not putting anything in the form. Then in MySQL, it turns 0 instead of being blank.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's string

```
$c_no        = mysql_real_escape_string("$_REQUEST['cs']");
$t_r        = mysql_real_escape_string("$_REQUEST['t_r']");
```

or

```
$c_no        = mysql_real_escape_string( strval($_REQUEST['cs']) );
$t_r        = mysql_real_escape_string( strval($_REQUEST['t_r']) );
```

Try to put `''` to the `varchar` values

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year, case_no, t_received) 
                VALUES ($year[$k], '$c_no[$k]', '$t_r[$k]')");
```

Comment: I think I saw the problem now, I updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: You (and the OP as well) are mixing mysql_* functions and mysqli.

Comment: @VolkerK I never thought about that haha.

Answer (score 1):

I'll help you through the **decoding** part of the request, the rest is already answered before by @rmondesilva (by putting quote on VARCHARs).

```
$year_param = $_REQUEST['year'];
$case_param = $_REQUEST['cs'];
$time_param = $_REQUEST['t_r'];

if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && isset($_REQUEST['year']) ) {

  foreach ($_REQUEST['year'] as $k=> $value ){ // loop through array

    $year     = $year_param[$k];
    $c_no        = mysql_real_escape_string($case_param [$k]);
    $t_r        = mysql_real_escape_string($time_param [$k]);


$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firearms_id_secs (year, case_no, t_received) VALUES 
   ($year, '$c_no', '$t_r')");
}
```

consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for your project though

Comment: You (and the OP as well) are mixing mysql_* functions and mysqli.

Comment: @VolkerK I just edited his code to show clarity on his logic, though I **did** suggest him using PDO at the end of the answer. I also stated that I'll only help him **decoding** the request